# How to display portrait mode in cocos2d-x 2.2.3

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am developing a game in xcode using cocos2d-x 2.2.3. I want to change the mode from landscape to portrait. I used the following code in rootviewcontroller.mm file. But still its not working. Please anyone can help me. Thanks

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( interfaceOrientation );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Rootviewcontroller.mm class change the code as following.

```
- (void)didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSLog(@"didFinishBannerViewActionNotification");
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( interfaceOrientation );
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
#endif
}
```

and in the xcode click your project name and in the general category change the Device orientation to portrait. I hope it will work.